# What to call a check-for-cache function?

Tags: caching, naming

An API supplies the function `get_object()`. Now, I'm writing an own function that either calls `get_object()`, or, if the object is cached, returns the cached object instead. What to call that function?

I think `get_cached_object()` implies that it already is cached, which might not be the case.

Comment: While I often have issues coming up with the perfect name for things, I don't think it's a valid StackOverflow question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Why not? I'm looking for a descriptive function name for something that appears often, in order to write better code. It's definitely not too localized, as this would apply to almost every program involving cache.

Comment: At first I also had the feeling of "not belongs here", but then I've checked the description on stack exchange's index: "programmers": "Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development" while "stackoverflow": "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers". So, for me, it seems it matches both of them well, while still I have doubts and I'd probably move it to "programmers". Yet, I do not know why and I cannot give any reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to name such methods "fetch" to relate to the term "fetch from cache". For me it just sounds like "caching may occur", instead of "get" with normal meaning, that is: no meaning instead of "gimme".

For example, singleton or caching factory: "fetchOrCreate"
Internet download or fetch from cache: "fetchOrDownload"

If you don't like the sound of it, I'd propose simple "getCachedObjectInstance" or "getCachedObject". It is enough to indicate the existence of cache, and I think it is OK for a method with such name to also initialize or update the cache as needed.

Comment: Heh, only after writing this, I've noticed you've already proposed get_cached_object:) sorry, it's kind of late here, with 02:30 AM I feel excused for any misreads :)))